# Save DOM element into a variable with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a side-menu-bar with some dropdown-lists. When i click on a list's child element, the menu closes. When i click again on the menu, i want that dropdown list to be expanded. In this way, i thought that it will be alright to save the DOM element into a global variable, and expand it on `onClick` menu event.

That list contains `li` and `ul` elements, to expand that, i'll add a `.css` class named "open".

The menu items didn't have any `id-s` to identify them.

How can i do this?

```
globally {var selectedItem =null}



   // If user click any menu link
    $('.menu-layer a').on('click', function () {
   //--> selectedItem = getClickedElement
   //... other code
 }


  //If user clicks the hamburger menu
    listenForMenuLayer: function () {
    $('.nav-menu').on('click', function () {
   //--> selectedClick.addClass('open')
    //animation and other stuff code
     }}
```

Thanks

Comment: Show us some code, please.

Comment: Please provide your code so it will be easy to  access your issue

Comment: Please check this http://www.jqueryscript.net/tags.php?/side%20menu/  it will help you

Comment: The menu worked well, the only thing is : i want to remember the clicked element and expand it's childs (if it has) when the menu is opened again

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this, not saving it as a global variable but just listening for the click event to fire like this, I'd also suggest adding at least on id on the parent of it all so it's easier to target.

```
$( "#menu" ).on( "click", function() {
    $( "#menu" ).addClass( "open" )
});
```